# How to pass comma delimited string to where clause in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query.  When I run it, I get  the errors.  What is the best way to do this?

```
declare @Slots varchar(50)
set @Slots = '1,2'
select * from Schedules where SlotID in (@Slots)
```

Error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Conversion failed when converting
> the varchar value '1,2' to data type int.

Comment: Addressing the "why": According to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), when you combine an (assumed) `int` (`SlotId`) with a string (`'1,2'`) in an expression (`SlotID in (@Slots)`) the string will get converted to an `int` in order to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also JOIN with [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) table-valued function that splits a string into rows of substrings, based on a specified separator character. See following example:

```
DECLARE @Schedules TABLE(SlotID int);
INSERT @Schedules VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);

DECLARE @Slots varchar(50);
SET @Slots = '1,2';

SELECT *
FROM @Schedules S
JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@Slots, ',') ON S.SlotID=value
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not support macro substitution.  You can, however, use `string_split()`

```
declare @Slots varchar(50)
set @Slots = '1,2'

Select * 
 From  Schedules 
 Where SlotID in (select Value from string_split(@Slots,','))
```